# Facing Timing Issues: SFTPing tar file and uncompressing in python

Tags: python, sftp, tar, timing

I am trying to tar set of folders containing xml files from a specific location on the remote server and trying to copy it locally and un-tarrring the same in python.

1. tared the file using the command `tar -cvf`
2. used the following code in Python to sftp the tarred file:

   ```
   sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
   sftp.get(remotePath, localPath, callback)
   sftp.close()
   ssh.close()
   ```
3. The callback function:

   ```
   def callback(transferred, tobetransferred):
       global transfer_complete
       res = abs(tobetransferred - transferred)
       if res == 0:
           transfer_complete = True
   ```
4. I check for the flag transfer_complete to be true or wait till it becomes true snippet:

   ```
   while transfer_complete == False:
       time.sleep(1)
   ```

**Problem faced here:**

I sometimes get this error:

```
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

which seems to be more of a timing issue as i see the tar file is copied intact but still it says could not untar. I see this problem for every 20-30 retries.

Is there an efficient way of doing this and removing this timing issue? Because I think the file is being copied still and i try to untar it.

Comment: What's the point o the callback? Do you untar from a different thread? Why do you use a callback to check for transfer completeness? Why don't you just untar after `ssh.close`?

Comment: @Martin reason for using callback is that i have next statements after sftp.close, ssh.close which tries to untar this file which has been copied to local repo from the remote. So i used this callback to check if the transfer is complete and then untar the file. But i see this timing issue inspite of that.

Comment: BTW there is no threads involved here. So waiting for some suggestions out here.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. Show us a complete code, including the untar part.